# Why does the same repository on different machines appear to have a different structure in Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I have two PCs each with Visual Studio 2019. I have the same repository on each machine, on the same branch, both recently synchronised with origin. They appear to have exactly the same files (although I've not checked them all).

The repository is for a C# asp.net Core solution containing 6 projects.

The dependencies node under two of these projects appears to differ depending on which machine I view them;

[image]

[image]

What might be causing this discrepency and how might I resolve it?

I have tried deleting the entire repository from one machine and cloning it again. I have tried closing and reopening Visual Studio, I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution, I have turned my machine on and off.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking what do those yellow warnings say. Besides checking the VS 2019 version installed in both machines, as well as compare the .Net Core SDK version.